# How to define BackboneJS models and collections that have an additional paramenter in the URL?

Tags: backbone.js

I have a model (and it's corresponding collection) that have an URL with an additional parameter. For instance, the URL for the posts `collection` would be something like:

```
/rest-api/posts/2/comments/
```

and for a particular comment the URL would be something like:

```
/rest-api/posts/2/comments/3/
```

What's the best pattern to define and instantiate the comments collection and models?

I'm currently doing this:

```
var Comment = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: function () {
        var base = '/rest-api/posts/' + this.get('post_id') + '/comments/';
        if (this.isNew()) { return base; }
        return base + this.id + '/';
    },
    // ...
});

var CommentsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Comment,
    url: function () {
        return '/rest-api/posts/' + this.post_id + '/comments/';
    },
    initialize: function (options) {
         this.post_id = options.post_id;
    },
    // ...
});
```

And instantiate the collection like this:

```
CommentsList = new CommentsCollection({ post_id: current_post_id });
```

Is this the `accepted` pattern for doing this in Backbone.js? I'm introducing myself to this  new framework, I just want to code this in a readable and maintainable way.

Comment: It is absolutely fine, using collection attributes does solve problems sometimes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need to define `url` in the Model since Backbone will append the id automatically to the Collection url: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url

Regarding the collection url, this is in my opinion a perfectly valid method of getting the url.

Alternatively, but adding complexity, you can add the Comments Collection as a property of the Post model and initialize or fetch it when needed. That way you can, if you prefer, add a `parent` property on the Collection and refer to that for getting the base url and append the `/comments` part (that should avoid having to change things in two places if the post url changes).

The choice, in the end, depends on the level of complexity you are willing to handle.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the model's URL being guessed using the URL of it's collection. However, In this case I must define an `url` method for the model anyway. The generated URL for the model results in something like `/rest-api/posts/2/comments/3` but the server needs the trailing `/`. Anyway, thanks! About definin the comments collection instance as an attribute of the post model, I'll definitely use this pattern, makes a lot of sense for me.